# dplyr filter function broken using R 3.1.2

Tags: r, dplyr

Using dplyr version 0.3.0.2 with R version 3.1.2 with an empty workspace.

Filter function does not recognize table fields so fails.  Other dplyr functions do.  Can someone test/validate?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect others to test if you don't supply any code to be tested/reproduced? Btw, I haven't noticed any unusual filter behavior in dplyr 0.3.0.2 yet.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  I am using R Studio and have a .Rprofile file in the project directory that was set to load dplyr at startup.  This caused dplyr to be after stats on the search path.  Thus, when I would call filter, it was calling the stats package function.  When I loaded dplyer after stats, everything worked fine.